# Python: reconnect client socket

Tags: python, sockets

How can I reconnect to the same server socket with my client socket? There was a similar question on SO with a vage (still unaccepted answer).

My server side looks like this

```
import socket
TCP_IP = '192.168.0.12'
TCP_PORT = 28478
BUFF_SZE = 1024
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.settimeout(10)
my_socket.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
my_socket.listen(1)
con, addr = my_socket.accept()
while 1:
    data = con.recv(BUFF_SZE)
    if data:
        print(data.decode())
        con.send(("world").encode()
con.close()
```

And my client side looks like this

```
import socket

TCP_IP = "192.168.0.12"
TCP_PORT = 28478
BUFF_SZE = 1024

sckt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sckt.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

MSG = "Hello"
sckt.send(MSG.encode())
data = sckt.recv(BUFF_SZE)
print(data.decode())

MSG = "Again"
sckt.send(MSG.encode())
data = sckt.recv(BUFF_SZE)
print(data.decode())


sckt.close()
```

Now, the client side successfully makes two transmits to the server and gets a response. However, I can't run the client side script twice... Server doesn't seem to get any input and hence the client doesn't get a response.
I thought this would be possible since I close the socket on the client side at end of script, so there must be something happening (or NOT happening) on the server side.
Should I do `my_socket.accept()` inside the server while loop?

Comment: The server never leaves its `while 1:` loop when it receives `EOF` from the socket. It just keeps trying to read even though the client has closed the socket.

Comment: And if you want to be able to handle multiple clients concurrently, you need to process each connection in its own thread, or use `select()` to poll all the sockets.

Comment: If you just want to handle one connection at a time, you need nested loops: The outer loop calls `accept`, the inner loop calls `recv` until EOF or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the server side to the following after comment by @Barmar

```
import socket
TCP_IP = '192.168.0.12'
TCP_PORT = 28478
BUFF_SZE = 1024
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.settimeout(10)
my_socket.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
my_socket.listen(1)
con, addr = my_socket.accept()
while 1:
    data = con.recv(BUFF_SZE)
    if data:
        print(data.decode())
        con.send(("world").encode()
    if not data:
        con, addr = my_socket.accept()

con.close()
```

So whenever the client kills the socket, the server accepts a new connections.